# most trivial React Router usecase not working - Route won't render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm writing my first React app, in Typescript.

Following a tutorial, I've created a single `<Link>` that references a single `<Route>` all inside my `<Router>` component. When I click the Link in my browser, the URL changes, but the Route does not render. I *cannot* figure out why the Route does not render. I've read a bunch of SO questions, but they're all related to advanced uses of Router; I can't get the most basic usecase to work.

Here's my top-level component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {StaticComponent} from "./StaticComponent/StaticComponent";

export default class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <header className="App-header">
                        <span>header</span>
                        <Link to="/staticComponent">Static Component</Link>
                    </header>
                    <main>
                        <span>body</span>
                        <Route path="/staticComponent" element={StaticComponent}/>
                    </main>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
```

Here's StaticComponent:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

export function StaticComponent () {
    return (
        <h2>You are at Static Component</h2>
    );
};
```

As you can see, top-level component displays as you'd expect:
[image: image of top-level component rendering correctly]

But when I click the link, the StaticComponent does not display:
[image: image of Static Component not rendering]

Is there some small detail I'm getting wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: it should be `component={StaticComponent}` not `element={StaticComponent}`

Comment: That fails to build with the error *TS2322: Type '{ path: string; component: FunctionComponent<{}>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<RouteProps, "path" | "caseSensitive"> & Pick<InferProps<{ caseSensitive: any; children: any; element: any; path: any; }>, "children" | "element"> & Pick<...>'.   Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<RouteProps, "path" | "caseSensitive"> & Pick<InferProps<{ caseSensitive: any; children: any; element: any; path: any; }>, "children" | "element"> & Pick<...>'.*

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out how to use the "element" attribute on the `<Route>` element, nor the "component" attribute that @gbalduzzi mentioned. However, implementing App.tsx in the following way does work:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {StaticComponent} from "./StaticComponent/StaticComponent";

export default class App extends Component<{}, {}>{
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <header className="App-header">
              <span>header</span>
              <Link to="/staticComponent">Static Component</Link>
            </header>
            <main>
              <span>body</span>
              <Route path="/staticComponent">
                <StaticComponent />
              </Route>
            </main>
          </Router>
        </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Also, line 2 of StaticComponent.tsx seems to have been unnecessary; I have since taken it out.

Finally, make sure you're using the correct version of React Router. The JSX files that work for React Router 5 do not seem to work for React Router 6.